# Convert seconds to minutes

Tags: bash, awk

I currently have a function that prints the position and duration from cmus and formats it like "1/500". The issue I'm having is that I would like the position and duration data to be presented in minutes as opposed to seconds (0:01/8:20 instead of 1/500) but I'm out of ideas on how to achieve this.

Currently the relevant part of the function looks like this:

```
print_music(){
    if ps -C cmus > /dev/null; then
        position=`cmus-remote -Q |
            grep --text '^position' |
            sed -e 's/position //' |
            awk '{gsub("position ", "");print}'`
        duration=`cmus-remote -Q |
            grep --text '^duration' |
            sed -e 's/duration //' |
            awk '{gsub("duration ", "");print}'`
        echo "[$position/$duration]"; else echo "";
    fi
}
```

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/q/13422743/4023950 what you need?

Comment: Using `date -d@$variable +%-M%S` does the conversion but unlike @glenn jackman solution, `date` will wrap to `0:00` at 3,600 secs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will help you:

```
sec2min() { printf "%d:%02d" "$((10#$1 / 60))" "$((10#$1 % 60))"; }
```

```
$ sec2min 500
8:20
$ sec2min 1
0:01
```

Comment: Here's the same operation using a second iteration of awk ... `awk '{ min = ($1 / 60)-(($1 % 60)*1/60) ; sec = $1 % 60 ; print min,":",sec}'`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the exact same thing. Using the awk method from @RubberStamp's comment on @glenn jackman's answer I ended up with the following which displays: e.g.

`2:07 / 4:08`

```
cmus-remote -Q | egrep "^duration|position" \
| tr '\n' ' ' \
| sed "s#^duration \|position ##g" \
| awk '{print ($2 / 60)-(($2 % 60)*1/60) ":" ($2 % 60), "/", ($1 / 60)-(($1 % 60)*1/60) ":" ($1 % 60)}' \
| sed "s#:\([0-9]\)\( \|\$\)#:0\1\2#g#";
```

Note: the last sed expression adds in leading `0`s so that `2:7 / 4:8` displays properly as `2:07 / 4:08` instead.