# Get total duration of video files in a directory in hours

Tags: bash

Based from: [Get total duration of video files in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170961/get-total-duration-of-video-files-in-a-directory)

But I need my output to be in hours. Been trying for some time to make this one line output to hours:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc
```

Any help? Hope it's not a duplicate because all the answer there only output in seconds which is bad and I don't have hope anyone will add to that question anymore

Comment: To get hours from seconds, you just need to divide by 60 × 60.

Comment: But how to do that after BC? The output is stored in the stdin, which is why i'm struggling to use it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `| paste -sd+ -| bc`, you can use `awk`:

```
find ... | awk '{s+=$0} END {print s/3600}'
```

This will print hours with decimals, but if you want more advanced output like Hours:Minutes:Seconds, check e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510132/convert-seconds-to-minutes) or check the `exiftool` option from the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170961/get-total-duration-of-video-files-in-a-directory) in your Question.

Comment: Perfect. Indeed much simpler than trying to do math with the output of bc stored in /dev/stdin

Answer (score 2):

That boils down to how to divide a number from the output of a command by 3600.

Which you could do with:

```
... | awk '{print $0 / 3600}'
```

Though here, you can do the whole thing with:

```
exiftool -r -n -q -p '${Duration;$_ = (our $total += $_) / 3600}' . | tail -n 1
```

(or `$_ = ConvertDuration(our $total += $_)` to express it like [`4 days 22:14:59`](/a/587665)).

Comment: My issue was that most of the answers for how to divide the output of a command by 3600 is that my value was in the /dev/stdin and not really a variable